# Odd-length cycles on the knight's graph

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Given an infinite chessboard, how many moves can a knight make such that it returns to its starting square, but doesn't visit any other square more than once?  It seems clear to me that the minimum number of moves is 4, and that there is no maximum.  I can also construct sequences of length 6, 8, etc.  But are there any sequences of odd length?

I think my question is equivalent to asking whether, on an infinite knight's graph, there exist any cycles of length 2k + 1 for k > 2.

Comment: The minimum number of moves is actually $2$.

Comment: Make use of the coloring of the chessboard..

Comment: Quite right, the minimum number of moves is 2.  I'd been thinking of the problem in terms of the graph, and the 2-move solution doesn't form a loop since it uses a single edge.

Comment: Thanks, @Christian. I see now that the squares visited by the knight always alternate in colour, so it's impossible to visit a square of the same colour in an odd number of moves.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Could you make an answer based on that observation?

Comment: Psychonaut, what you are calling a "loop" is usually called a "cycle" in English. The term "loop" is reserved for a cycle of length $1$, consisting of an edge joining a vertex to itself.

Answer (score 3):

Converting my comment into a hint:

Make use of the coloring of the chessboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of this problem as one in linear algebra. You have a "basis" of moves you can make. Which linear combinations of them (over $\mathbb{Z}) give you the zero vector? Please note that a lot of the above may need to be taken quite loosely.